# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/users/762146111"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've been following the Michael Hartl tutorial for learning rails and have been doing pretty well thus far, but I'm stumped on this issue which I've encountered repeatedly. I'm not skilled enough to know if there is a configuration problem in my environment or something else, but this makes NO sense to me.

In ANY of the controller tests I attempt to run, I can never get my helper URL methods to work. As an example:

```
  test "should redirect home when not an admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete user_path(@user)
    end
    assert redirect_to root_url    
  end
```

Generates the following error:

```
ERROR["test_should_redirect_home_when_not_an_admin", UsersControllerTest, 0.9899668790167198]
 test_should_redirect_home_when_not_an_admin#UsersControllerTest (0.99s)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:         ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/users/762146111", :controller=>"users"}
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:59:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Even simple tests like

```
 test "should redirect index when not logged in" do
     get users_path
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

Produce the same error:

```
ERROR["test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 1.5291320629185066]
 test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1.53s)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:         ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/users", :controller=>"users"}
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:34:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Everything I've googled about this issue hasn't helped, because for some reason I cannot determine the user_path method (or any other similar method) somehow thinks the action I'm trying to take in my controller is the path!

I've verified that my routes file is configured correctly.

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/help'     => 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about'    => 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact'  => 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/signup'   => 'users#new'
  post '/signup'  => 'users#create'
  get '/login'    => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'sessions/new'
  resources :users
end
```

I've checked that running "rails routes" has the correct routes. I've even checked in rails console that "app.user_path(1)" spits out a valid path.

At this point I'm just beyond stumped as to why these helper methods don't seem to be helping... I also don't know what they're actually called so my googling has been fairly fruitless.

To get around this issue in the tutorial, I've been using syntax like

```
patch :edit, { id: @user }, params: { user: { name: @user.name,
                                          email: @user.email }}
```

Or

```
  test "should redirect index when not logged in" do
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

Which seems to work.

Also here is one of my test files if that's helpful:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when user not logged in" do
    get :edit, params: { id: @user }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when user not logged in" do
    patch :edit, { id: @user }, params: { user: { name: @user.name,
                                              email: @user.email }}
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url   
  end

  test "should redirect index when not logged in" do
    # get users_path
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end


  test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete user_path(@user)
    end
    assert redirect_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect home when not an admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete user_path(@user)
    end
    assert redirect_to root_url    
  end

end
```

Please let me know what other files I can post to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by changing the file 'users_controller_test.rb' file replacing:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
```

for

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

But first, in your case, check that you have in your Gemfile the line:

```
gem 'rails',        '5.0.1'
```

as the tutorial shows.

I can also see that you have the following test:

```
test 'should get new' do
  get :new
  assert_response :success
end
```

When you make the correction you'll have to change the above test to:

```
test 'should get new' do
  get new_user_path
  assert_response :success
end
```

After that, run your tests and you should have them all passed.

Hope it helps